# Why is the configuration file in the parameter list of make command?

Tags: make

Here is the command line I got from a chip maker:

```
make sunxi_defconfig ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-
```

It surely failed with message of

```
*** Error during writing of the configuration.
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:121: nanopi_h3_defconfig] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:479: nanopi_h3_defconfig] Error 2
```

I found `sunxi_defconfig` from folder `configs/`. Why is the configuration file `sunxi_defconfig` put on parameter list as a target on `make` command? I studied `make` command manual carefully and didn't find the case of putting a configuration file as a making target.
Is the command line wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: I think the trouble coming from "Error during writing ..." because it's gone after I added 'sudo' before 'make'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel build recognises `defconfig` file names as targets for builds using that default configuration. If you run

```
make ARCH=arm help
```

you’ll see them listed at the end; they include

```
  sunxi_defconfig             - Build for sunxi
```

`make sunxi_defconfig ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-` is a valid invocation for an `arm` cross-compiling build using the `sunxi` default configuration, and a toolchain prefixed with `arm-linux-`.

As for you error, you’ll need to look further up in the build output to see if there’s anything more specific.

Comment: You said "The kernel build recognizes ...", but I don't remember this kind of concept when I studied 'man make'. Could you please tell me where I can study such concept?

Comment: It’s a feature of the kernel build, not of Make itself — so Make doesn’t document it. The kernel Makefiles are [partially documented in the kernel itself](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html), but the main “documentation” is `make help` in the kernel (which is also a feature of the kernel build, not of Make).